# Better alternatives to "Save me!" - meaning to save electricity

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, translation

There is a sign on the light switch at a bilingual school to encourage students to switch off the lights when not in use and help save energy:

> Save me!

[image]

Translating "Save me!" to Slovak, would be:

> save me => zachráň ma

Which sounds correct, meaning "save me from [something]".

Google Translate gives the below for the correct Slovak term as in "save electricity", I guess that is how school decided to use "Save me!" on the switches:

> šetrí ma => save me

This doesn't sound right to me, but I cannot think of any other better alternative that is short and concise enough that would fit on a switch button.

---

**Update:** I will contact the school, and see what option they prefer. Then accept the answer accordingly. Thank you for all the answers/comments.

Comment: Do you want single-word alternatives for 'save me!'? And do you want English alternatives or Slovak ones?

Comment: @Ahmed I only need English version, doesn't have to be a single word (but if only possible, the shorter the better). Slovak version **is** correct.

Comment: I think the sign maker was being a bit playful here, and meant to evoke both meanings in the mind of the reader...

Comment: @colmde Lovely to think this way, but I doubt it, this is best they could do. I have seen many mistakes before at this school, and asked to school to fix it. They are very welcoming for suggestions and do correct mistakes happily.

Comment: @zx8754 - even if it was unintentional '*Save me!*' is very good:  the idea that energy should not be wasted and is also a finite resource.

Comment: @Dan It is quite possible that it is the only *good* option. But if I hear someone scream "Save me!" I would assume someone is in trouble and needs help. In this case, switch is not in trouble and doesn't need saving from anything, it is just doing its job: switch lights on/off. Somehow being "off" is more preferable to the switch.

Comment: If the note is supposed to be amusing then it works but it is ambiguous. "Save me" from what? Who is attacking me? It's as if the light switch has been personified. However, in English we do this all the time: "She's [the car] running a bit low [on petrol]." But if it is a message to students to remind them to switch off the lights then "Save Electricity/Energy/Power" are preferable.

Comment: This doesn't really sound right in English either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, a bit lost, what are you referring to as "This"?

Comment: @zx8754 The original usage of "Save me!" on the lightswitch.

Comment: I ... think it sounds fine. I instantly understood the intended meaning, where "me" is electricity. Not sure why there's so much discussion tbh.

Comment: My goodness, it should be: Don't waste me. Resources of whatever kind should not be wasted.

Comment: The pun is almost certainly intentional. "Don't waste me" and "conserve me" are boring and will easily be ignored. "Save me" is harder to ignore, it's something someone normally says in an emergency.

Comment: - - -  save E - - -

Comment: I get the joke, but it borders on dangerous because it sets a precedence which may cause people to disregard a note from somebody who is actually in distress. The fact that it's printed gives it away, because you can't expect somebody in imminent danger to wait for it to finish printing. However, what happens now when somebody writes this on a sticky note with sharpie and puts it next to a light switch, hoping that it'd be noticed and alert somebody that something's actually wrong? "Oh yeah, I forgot to turn off the light." Granted, that's quite unlikely, but is it even worth a slight risk?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I suppose **conserve** would be a more correct (or at least less ambiguous) term for what's meant.

But as I said in the comment, "Save me!" is a bit funnier and draws your attention as it personifies the electricity (or the light switch) a little, like it's asking for your help as well as asking you to save electricity.

Comment: Yeah, [conserve] would be a bit dull and more confusing than helpful. But "Save me" still doesn't makes sense, even if we imagine switch is talking to us: "save me (from what?)".

Comment: _Save_ doesn't have to mean saving/rescuing from something. It also means, in this instance, preserve/don't use. So 'Don't use me' would mean the same thing.

Comment: zx8754 - 'But "Save me" still doesn't makes sense.' It does to me. True, you are not _literally_ saving the life of the light-switch. You are _saving_ (conserving) the energy it uses (you're using less). And you are _saving_ the planet's life.

Comment: Just *conserve* on its own would be a bit strange. *Conserve energy* would be better—and is often seen.

Comment: @JasonBassford agree "Conserve energy" could work, but might lose its appeal with younger students. Or as suggested "Turn off", "Switch off" would work better than conserve.

Comment: @user2397282 Except that “Don't use me” sounds like a mandate.  I would put that label on a switch which should not be operated — though I would be more likely to disconnect whatever piece of equipment I didn't want operated, or to hang one of my red Danger tags on it.

Comment: @NigelTouch So, shouldn't it be a little Earth with a face, or maybe an image of the overworked generator or turbine oh so far away?  Even so, maybe “protect me” or “don't waste me” would be better.

Answer (score 22):

**Save me** is fine because it **does not necessarily only mean** to ***save*** s*omething or someone* ***from*** *something*.

If you look at the Oxford Dictionaries Online definitions for [**save**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/save), you'll see five definitions including the following:

> Keep safe or rescue (someone or something) from harm or danger.
>
> - ‘they brought him in to help save the club from bankruptcy’

The definition above fits the *save from* context

The definition relevant to the ***save electricity*** context is actually:

> **Preserve** (something) **by not expending or using it**.
>
> - ‘save your strength till later’

Comment: Probably the most common example of the last use would be _save money_. For example, "_I'm saving_ [my money] _for a new computer_".

Comment: Correct.  And they slapped it on that switch because it's an *electric* switch.

Answer (score 17):

I would say "save me" is fine in English. It ends up as somewhat of a pun, which doesn't translate well and might have been unintentional, but I don't think that detracts from the message.

It's common in English to talk about "saving electricity" or saving some other resource like money. This is listed as definition 4 of Save on [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/save?s=t):

> to avoid the spending, consumption, or waste of

This works fairly well, and is extremely common in English. The only point for potential confusion is that the label is on a switch, so it could come across more as "save the light switch" rather than "save electricity". This is also where the double-meaning comes in; this interpretation invokes definition 1 or 2 instead:

> 1. to rescue from danger or possible harm, injury, or loss
> 2. to keep safe, intact, or unhurt; safeguard; preserve

In this context, the object is being personified and asking for help in some way. "Save me!" without any indication as to what they might need saving from is perfectly acceptable in English, though it does imply that there is some kind of danger that exists.

For a fluent English speaker, I think "Save me!" is fine and the dual interpretations are likely to be clear enough to understand, while the slight pun and personification will make the message more memorable and eye-catching. However, since the message is intended for a "bilingual school" it's possible that the double-meaning will be more confusing than it is worth. An alternative would be the more unambiguous "Save electricity!" which dodges the second meaning arising from "me". A shorter version could be "Save power"; it seems awkward to me, but it's comprehensible enough.

Answer (score 10):

You could better come up with the most precis option: [**Save Energy!**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=56A263403dw) or you can say "[**Save Power!**](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cf/e2/01/cfe2011268e35ef179d94d4343eba770.jpg)." I am sure that these two phrases have direct message to conserve electricity, as "Save me!" might lead the reader to another sense.

As [colmde](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/157317/colmde) thinks about "Save me!" phrase that the "sign maker
was being a bit playful
here, and meant to evoke
both meanings in the
mind of the reader..."

> Example poster image from previews.123rf.com:
>
> [image: save energy poster]

Comment: I agree that this is the best option, but I think it could do with some more explanation as to *why*. The reason being that in "save me" stuck to a light switch, the "me" is the light switch. We don't want to save the light switch, we want to save energy/electricity. The intention of the current note is relatively clear from the context, but it's not colloquial, and schools generally aim to teach idiomatic phrases when teaching languages.

Comment: @AndyT : also the "me" might refer to the person placing the sticker. My first reaction would be to become alarmed, maybe someone is in danger (abused, kidnapped) and is trying to cry for help without alerting the abuser.

Answer (score 7):

What about "Switch off!" or "Turn off!" ?

Comment: I like this option, but it sounds more like a command, than a kind request.

Comment: @zx8754 "_Please_ turn off"?! ;)

Answer (score 6):

There was an energy conservation campaign a while back that used the slogan

> Save a watt!

another slogan used the phrase

> [Kill a watt!](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project-ideas/Energy_p020/energy-power/spare-a-watt-save-a-lot)

The literal meaning is clear and this is also a pun of the word "kilowatt" which is part of the most common unit in which energy usage is billed by utilities, the kilowatt hour.

Answer (score 5):

How about phrasing it as a request or mandate in the negative?

> Do not waste me!
>   Don't waste me!

‘[Waste](https://wiktionary.org/wiki/waste#Verb)’ here being the transitive form of the verb rather than the uncountable noun — the noun which is synonymic with ‘rubbish’, ‘trash’, ‘[refuse](https://wiktionary.org/wiki/refuse#Noun)’, ‘garbage’, or what–have–you.
You could also say

> Don't squander me!

And, perhaps you should, because that word — from my experience — isn't often heard or read except in certain contexts:  some people may not be readily familiar with the word, or may think it quaint, but either one will attract attention and shouldn't obfuscate the sentence unless the person is almost illiterate in English or has a very small English vocabulary.  I think most English–speaking people are aware of the word ‘squander’ and what it conveys.

The added benefit with my recommendation is that it accommodates use — you can use it, but don't waste it.  Of course, so too does the [conserve](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/463774/210023) one.

Comment: Yes, but the abbreviated form.

Answer (score 4):

I think the intent is to say 'Don't forget to switch off after use'. A version of 'Don't waste energy/me' or a lengthier command "Switch off after use' are viable alternatives. I think you have to work with the space constraint of the switch size but depending on how important clear instruction needs to be, you can use 'save power', 'save earth', 'save life', 'use judiciously'.

Comment: Thanks, already got many good alternatives, yes the space is the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

The word "save" frames the problem as if there is a fixed amount of energy that must be allocated efficiently over time -- "save it now, and you can use it later". Efficiently "saving" energy that is already on the power grid is not really an option with current technology, from what I understand. Instead, I guess the environmental goal is to reduce the amount of energy that is produced in the first place.

You could use "waste not", short for "waste not, want not", [defined in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waste_not,_want_not) as...

> (idiomatic) If one is not wasteful then one will not be in need.

This idiom is usually for individuals and households, but it can also apply to us all collectively in the context of energy usage, like...

> If we don't produce more energy than we need, there will be plenty.

Here, "plenty" can refer to not only energy, but also other resources (through [externalities](https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Negative_externality#Externalities_from_Electricity_Production)).

Comment: You seem to be assuming that _save_ connotes gradual accumulation (or at least, reduced expenditure) of a limited resource now for the specific purpose of having a larger quantity of that resource available for use at a later time. But that's not necessarily so; the verb _save_ can also mean simply to minimize waste. For example, this is the difference between _saving money_ for an intended future purchase, and _saving money_ by taking advantage of discounts when shopping.

Comment: @jdmc I think that the "saving by" example still implies the "saving for" interpretation. Whether I'm saving money, time, space, CPU cycles or my own mental or physical energy, the implication is that I have this resource and am saving it instead of wasting it, and that I am saving it because it can be put to other uses.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but in your example, if I cannot afford a purchase without taking advantage of the discount (eg, I have $20, the price is $30 without the discount and $10 with), then I think "saving money" is not correct there either -- I cannot save what I do not have.

Comment: @Frank saving money is absolutely correct there, independant of whether you can afford it without the discount. You are SPENDING LESS, which is one of the definitions of save on the oxford dictionary.

Comment: @Aethenosity After "spending less" implicitly comes "than you would have spent otherwise", which is not meaningful if the counterfactual where you spend more is infeasible (since you could not have afforded it). That's my reading of the word, anyways -- that you can only save things that exist. (I may lay off replying soon. The OP suggested I post this answer; and I fear that I'm not saying anything new in the comments here now.)

Comment: @Frank that's not my reading or understanding of it at all. Nor is it how it is used in the PNW in the US. Could be a regional difference maybe. Are you talking BrE. I'm from an AmE perspective

Comment: @Aethenosity Nope, AmE. Btw, you can see in my profile that I am in the United States (though, of course, I could still be here and non-native).

Answer (score 1):

My two suggestions are "**think twice**" or "**consider the cost**".

Multipurpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, "Use wisely" and "Act wise".